# PHP task won't quit after restarting Nginx and PHP

Tags: php, nginx, debian, fastcgi

I've been trying to solve this problem for the whole day now but I just can't find a working solution.

A few days ago, I've used a WordPress plugin that automatically deleted picture files that where not attached to any posts. It gave me a long list with files, and I selected all and pressed submit.

Since then, I can no longer access the website. "sudo service nginx restart" won't help. When I restart php5-fpm the other websites that are located on the server work as long as I don't access the faulty site.

The log says:

```
[error] 1953#0: *167262 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2013/08/d49a.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock", host: "..."
```

I've tried increasing fastcgi_read_timeout but that doesn't help either. When I move the faulty WordPress installation to another location and restart Nginx, there will be created a folder with the same name (/wp-content/uploads/...) with nothing in it.

To me it looks like there's a PHP task that is automatically started as soon as php5-fpm is running and then crashes over and over again. Is there a way to clear all tasks or processes that run through PHP/FastCGI? Or what else could be the problem?

Comment: Which wordpress plugin was it? (That might help someone diagnose the problem more easily.) It sounds to me like the problem only starts when you go to the faulty website, so that would rule out that it starts automatically with php5-fpm. Have you looked at your database, to see if there's something there you can throw away (like a list of all those unattached files)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it was the "WordPress Uploaded Files Cleaner".